# Diagnostic test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, diagnostic

I want to calculate the sensitivity, specificity, positive predictive value and negative predictive value of two diagnostic tests. The sensitivity is 0.92 (95% CI, 0.82-1.03)
Is this confidence interval possible?

Comment: Since you are the one doing the calculation, could you please tell us how you computed such a confidence interval?

Comment: I have used this formula ftp://ftp.hrc.es/pub/programas/calcu/prudiag/img/2.jpg

Comment: Just provide us the routine true positive, true negative, false positive and false negative figures and we can easily double check it.

Comment: True positive 24, true negative 70, false positive 0, false negative 2  thanks you

Comment: The issue is that sensitivity cannot exceed 1.  So the upper bound should be truncated at 1.  If an exact interval was generated you would not get 1.03.  What must be happening is that you are using an asymptotic distribution to generate the interval.  So the interval is approximate rather than exact. I think this is the reason whuber wants to know the formula you are using to calculate the interval.

Comment: How can I calculate the confidence intervals correctly?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the confidence interval, you used the formula $ Sen \pm 1.96 \sqrt{\dfrac{Sen(1-Sen)}{TP+FN}}$, where $Sen=TP/(TP+FN)$. This is an example of the normal approximation of the binomial distribution used to estimate the confidence interval. This is generally okay when $Sen(TP+FN)>5$ and $(1-Sen)(TP+FN)>5$. In your case, one of the conditions isn't met.

In general, it's much better to use exact binomial methods to calculate confidence intervals. You can do this easily in R.

```
> binom.test(24,26)

Exact binomial test

data:  24 and 26
number of successes = 24, number of trials = 26, p-value =  1.049e-05
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.7486971 0.9905446
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.9230769
```

You can see that the 95% confidence interval calculated using exact binomial methods is 75% to 99%. Ignore the p-value and alternative hypothesis.

With strong computing power available anywhere, I'm not sure there's a place for normal approximations.